# What permissions are needed in Cosmos Db to access to the database in the Azure portal and view data

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have an Azure Cosmos Db where it would be beneficial to allow some testers access to the database. I'm struggling finding which permissions should be granted so they could view the data in database without giving them Contributor permissions. The access could be through the Azure portal or through cosmos.azure.com.

Answer (score 1):

based on your requirement , it looks like you need to provide the role as  ["Cosmos DB Account Reader"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#cosmos-db-account-reader-role)

> Can read Azure Cosmos DB account data.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently *Cosmos DB Account Reader* permission is enough when the Data Explorer is accessed through the Azure portal. When the user is opening cosmos.azure.com, however, that permission is not enough.